# Feeding output of nvidia-smi to tail command returns error

Tags: pipe, tail, watch-command

I have a custom `nvidia-smi` message where some additional information (e.g., username) is also output underneath the original output of the `nvidia-smi` message.

I want to feed that output to a `tail` command so that I only see the bottom part of the message. How should I go about doing that?

Right now I have the following:

```
alias gpu='watch -n 1 "nvidia-smi | tee /dev/stderr | awk '"'"'/ C / {print \$3}'"'"' | xargs -r ps -up"'
```

which works fine. But again, it only shows the top portion.

In order to show the bottom portion, I've tried something like:

```
alias gpu2="watch -n 1 \"nvidia-smi | awk \"/ C / {print \$3}\" | xargs -r ps -up | tail -n $(($LINES - 2))\""
```

but when I run this command I get the following output:

```
Every 1.0s: nvidia-smi | awk / C {print } | xargs -r ps -up | tail -n 40

awk: cmd. line:1: /
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is and how to interpret the error message. I've tried escaping the slashes but that didn't work.

How should I go about solving this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Aliases are intended for simple textual substitutions - when you get to the point where multiple levels of nested quotes are required I'd recommend switching to a shell function. See for example [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't think of this option until now.